# Remove certain characters in a string using Windows command line

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a text file having the string:

```
pub: 
04:d6:b6:f2:98:ff:94:d8:3c:36:ad:5f:86:40:aa:
d1:5a:e1:87:5d:55:9d:ad:8b:2b:fc:18:e7:bb:47:
7f:9f:9a:62:c6:19:3a:9e:65:62:4e:5e:98:6d:db:
0e:7d:f9:22:a3:ca:cb:12:b2:ed:eb:14:0c:b3:31:
59:02:17:6d:6a
```

I need to remove the 04 from the beginning of this and also remove the ':' from between the characters and print it like this, in a single line:

```
d6b6f298ff94d83c36ad5f8640aad15ae1875d559dad8b2bfc18e7bb477f9f9a62c6193a9e65624e5e986ddb0e7df922a3cacb12b2edeb140cb3315902176d6a
```

How can I do that using Windows commands?

Comment: there is "Windows Batch" (built in) and "Bash for Windows" (third-party "unix"-add-on).What do you use?

Comment: What about `pub:`, do you need to remove that too?

Comment: I use Windows Batch. And yes, `pub:` has to be removed.

Comment: Is that the only string, _(entire content)_, of the text file? Is it Unicode or ASCII? with CR, LF, or CRLF line endings?

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own? Remember that StackOverflow is not a free code writing service!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

quite straightforward:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "first=true"
(for /f "eol=p delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
  set "line=%%a"
  if defined first (set "line=!line:~2!" & set "first=")
  <nul set /p ".=!line::=!"
))>output.txt
```

Read the input file line by line.
Use a flag (`first`) to check for first line and remove the first two chars.
Remove the colons and
use `<nul set /p` to write without a line break.

**Edit** as it turned out in comments, your file has actually just one long line. This changes the way for processing to:

```
for /f %%a in (input.txt) do set "line=%%a"
set "line=%line:pub:04:=%"
set "line=%line::=%"
echo %line%
```

Note: variables can just hold a certain amount of data, so this apporach will fail, when the line exceeds this limit.

Comment: Instead of `eol=p` I would use `skip=1`, but that seems to be a matter of taste due to poor specification...

Comment: yes, there is more than one way to skin a cat. Each has it's own advantages and disadvantages. I choosed this way, because `skip` does skip regardless of the content.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is pretty confusing. You first say: *"I have a text file having the string:"*, but the example data have *six lines* that could be taken as **six strings**, so at this point we have no idea of what the real data format is. Perhaps a single long line that you write here in six parts?

Next, you said *"I need to remove the 04 from the beginning of this"*, but what happen if the data have *not* a `04` at the beginning? Perhaps you want to remove *the first element* even if it is not a `04`?

In this way, we must *assume* several points in order to try to write a working solution.

The Batch file below read a file with *several lines*, remove *the first line* (even if it does not contain `pub:`), and remove *the first* colon-separated element (even if it is not `04`):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Read all lines, excepting the first one:
set "string="
for /F "skip=1" %%a in (input.txt) do set "string=!string!%%a"

rem Remove the first element:
set "string=%string:*:=%"

rem Show the rest, removing colons:
echo %string::=%
```

In this code there are other assumptions that are implicit in the way the commands work, like lines that does not contain spaces nor exclamation marks. Of course, if the real data file have a different format, this program will fail...

Comment: It is actually a single long line split into 6 parts. And the first colon separated element is always 04 in this case.

Comment: Your "explanation" just confuses the things even more: text files contain **lines**! (not _parts_ nor _strings_). Did your file contain _a single long line_ or contain _six lines_? Anyway, I think my code fullfill your requirements and produce the right output. Isn't it?

Comment: It has Six lines. And yes, your code has given the right output! Thanks!

Comment: @AkhilKintali please be precise. One line or several lines *do* make a difference. Note: both answers (mine and this one) will fail, when the line(s) is (are) too long, as there is a limit on how much a variable can store.