# How to get the first part of the first match in a text file using grep for Windows?

Tags: grep

New member but have been learning here for some time now.
I'm trying to get the first match from a txt file using grep for windows. This txt file is the index downloaded from e webpage,
with a list of Setup.exe files:

curl.exe --output index.txt --url "https://download.software.com/download/?C=M;O=D" --ssl-no-revoke

Where the setups are listed per last modified date. In this way I can get the latest setup.exe version.
Everything works fine until I try to get the string "SoftwarePremium0.0.0.0_Setup.exe"
I'm trying to get the first match with:

grep -o -m 1 "SoftwarePremium.*Setup.exe" index.txt > output.txt

The result in the output file is: SoftwarePremium0.0.0.0_Setup.exe">SoftwarePremium0.0.0.0_Setup.exe.
As this is how it appears in the input file.
I have three problems (Sorry).

1. The result in the output file is deleted when the batch file is closed. How can I save it?
2. How can I copy/save only the "SoftwarePremium0.0.0.0_Setup.exe" part of the output?
3. How can I put it at the end of the url to download the setup.exe?
   https://download.software.com/download/...
   Thank You.

Comment: 1) solved by simply adding to the batch: TYPE output.txt >> New_output.txt. 2) Solved thanks to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49913126/remove-certain-characters-in-a-string-using-windows-command-line

Comment: My only problem now is 3). Copy and paste output "SoftwarePremium0.0.0.0_Setup.exe" to the end of the line where the url is found.